# Java regular Expression End of String

Tags: java, expression

I want to replace some part of a string, but only if the part is the last part of the string.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void banana(){
        String test = "I love Banana";
        System.out.println("Test:  "+test+"\nRegEx: "+test.replace("a$","as"));
    }
}
```

The code above does not change anything. Without the $-sign I get `I love Basnasnas`, which is not, what I want. I tried escape the dollar with a backslash, didn't work out. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I have to use replaceAll instead of replace! Thank you!